# How do I copy a windows phone app to an actual device?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 App ; Have also created the .appx package from Visual Studio 2013.I don't want to upload it to the store.How do I copy the app to my phone via a USB connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register your phone as developer phone, now [launch the Application Deployment tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632395.aspx) (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\AppDeploy\AppDeploy.exe`) select your device and Appx file and click on deploy.

[image]