# Phonegap: deploy app on Windows Phone 8.1 manually

Tags: cordova, deployment, windows-phone-8.1

For my job I'm developing a Phonegap app, and we're at the stage where we can give the app to our testers. We've figured out how to do it for Android and iOS devices, but Windows Phone 8.1 devices remain quite elusive as to how to do this.

Is there a similar way, just like with Android, to mail the app-file to our testers so they can install it easy-peasy?

I've tried setting the app on the phone, going to the Store, Install Local Apps, but nothing came up. Tried opening the .appx file, but it gave an error, and lots of googling.

If anyone knows of a way, I'd love to hear it.

FYI: Our testers do not have access to our code, so they can't deploy via command console or through Visual Studio.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31968214/1466046

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @magicandre1981. We've informed our testers of this method.