# To install .appx of my windows phone application on Phone without submitting it to windows store

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I have developed a windows phone basic app and I want to install it on Phone without submitting it to store. I created App packages which has .appx file of my app. I have put that file in my phone but when I try to install it, it gives error

> can't install company app. 
>   There's a problem with this company app. Contact your company's support person for help.

Please let me know what should I do.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: I am getting the above stated error in phone

Comment: Please root your phone There is some privacy check setting

Comment: Can u please let me know what type of privacy setting it could be..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31968214/1466046

Comment: Yes that way is right I tried it but Appdeploy.exe is a part of visual stufio framework..
And I want to distribute my App to those who dont't have or use visual studio..can I not just distribute the .appx file and the person can install it through INSTALL LOCAL APP option of windows phone..
Is it possible?

Comment: nope, WindowsPhoe doesn't allow easy setup of apps (appx) like Android

Comment: ok..Thanks. but can anyone tell me how can we use the option of INSTALL LOCAL APP in windows phone. What is its use?