# Install xap file into Lumia 625 using the SD Card

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-build, xap

I am built a Windows Phone application with PhoneGap Build and I am trying to install it into a Nokia Lumia 625 with Software: Windows Phone 8.1.

I have installed the application on a Nokia Lumia 735 with Software: Windows 10 Mobile with no problems, for the Lumia 625 things seems much more complicated :(

To install the App on the Lumia 625, those should be the steps:
 1 - Download the application with extension .xap
 2 - Copy the file into the phone SD card
 3 - Go to the Windows Phone Store
 4 - Click the 3 dots on the bottom-right corner
 5 - Click on 'Install local apps'
At that point my application should be listed there and I should be able to install it.

My current problem is that after step 4, the option 'Install local apps' is not visible...I have download WhatsApp.xap from internet and when it is added to the SD Card that option shows up and I am able to install the application.

The above tells me that there is something wrong with my application but I don't understand what. Below there is a screenshot of what I have loaded into the SD Card: http://prntscr.com/h7a7d8

The current state is:
 - if both App are in the SD Card, 'Install local apps' is shown but only WhatsApp is listed
 - if I remove WhatsApp from the SD Card, 'Install local apps' is not shown

Can anyone help me to understand what could be wrong in my App to not being able to install it into Lumia 625 but working fine on the Lumia 735?

Please let me know if you guys need any further information as the config.xml or anything else and I'll be able to provide it

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy a windows phone app to an actual device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967678/how-do-i-copy-a-windows-phone-app-to-an-actual-device)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have at the end managed to solve this problem myself, I have opted for a different way to install the app.

By installing Windows 10 SDK, I had at my service a tool called 'Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1' and to get it to work I just need to connect the Phone through USB cable, select the APPX file I want to upload install to the phone and 'DEPLOY' :)

Here is a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/h7qdxj

Thanks guys anyway :)

Comment: this was [already asked and answered way ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31968214/1466046)